# Charset not working in .html but not .aspx

Tags: asp.net, html, character-encoding

When I put this word "Biblioth&egrave;que" in a .aspx page, I see it correctly "Bibliothèque".

If I put the same word in a .html file, I see "BibliothÃ¨que"

How can this be possible? Must be an IIS issue but I can't find the setting.

How can a .aspx file show the right word but not a .html file.

Comment: What meta tags appear for each? What http headers for each?

Comment: @Oded - I think your edit is misleading and should be rolled back. You have entitized the grave accent in the question, while the question is precisely about the fact the character is not properly encoded. I understood the question only when I looked at the original one.

Comment: The edit is wrong because the HTML file DOES contain &egrave;

Answer (score 0):

Open the file named web.config in the ASP.NET project. The value of requestEncoding attribute in globalization element is "utf-8". It means the requested texts were encoded as UTF-8 character set.

check your browser what it is support. you can change it using character encoding. So your HTML is giving you the result according to browser character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure it will always work, for this specific example, you can replace the non ASCII characters using [Html entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp), like this: `Biblioth&egrave;que`. But this is not always practical in general.

Otherwise, there are other various ways to make it work:

- use [byte order mark encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (sometimes called 'signature', or BOM, by editors) and save the file as UTF-8
- add a [META character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML) to your html file.
- define what HTTP headers will be sent to the client using the [globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) element in the application web.config (responseEncoding, etc.)
- define what HTTP headers will be sent to the client using the ASP.NET [@page directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx)

The best is to make sure all this is consistent in your application. UTF-8 support is now widespread, so it's a good choice as the encoding.

An interesting article on the encoding subject :[The Definitive Guide to Web Character Encoding](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-web-character-encoding/)